# How to avoid the "two bean definitions found" error

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a huge application with thousands of Spring beans registered using annotations and wired with each others with @Autowired
The application will be released as a "core" application and our customers should be able to customize it adding or overwriting beans.
If they hace to modify a bean the regular way would be by extending the class and making the Spring context to register the customized class **instead of** the "core" one, but doing that Spring throws an error because it finds two implementation for the same interface.
How can I achieve that?
How can our customers "de-register" the core class and regster the customizaed one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `@Qualifier` which would inject the dependencies based on names in case of multiple implementations of a type.

Answer (score 2):

[You can use a Qualifier. They identify beans by name, not by type.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm)

You also can set the field to a list of beans.

```
@Autowire
private Foobar[] customizedAndCore;
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of handling that is by using the [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation. Spring will inject the primary instead of failing with the duplicate bean exception.

Comment: +1 But the dynamic-generated `customized` bean shall be load. How do you add a @Primary to a session-bean dynamically?

Comment: @PeterRader I don't follow you? Why dynamic-generated? As far as i understand David releases a "Product" which can be customized by adding new classes by the client.

Comment: Well i think the customized-bean *can* be used and overwrite the core-bean, the decision occour at runtime. By generate i mean instantication.

Answer (score 1):

Here a basic draft to use @Qualifier plus @Autowired annotation

Here is the content of Student.java file:

```
public class Student {
   private Integer age;
   private String name;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Here is the content of Profile.java file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Profile {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("student1")
   //@Qualifier("student2")
   private Student student;

   public Profile(){
      System.out.println("Inside Profile constructor." );
   }

   public void printAge() {
      System.out.println("Age : " + student.getAge() );
   }

   public void printName() {
      System.out.println("Name : " + student.getName() );
   }
}
```

Following is the content of the MainApp.java file:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      Profile profile = (Profile) context.getBean("profile");

      profile.printAge();
      profile.printName();
   }
}
```

Consider the example of following configuration file Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>

   <!-- Definition for profile bean -->
   <bean id="profile" class="com.Profile">
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for student1 bean -->
   <bean id="student1" class="com.Student">
      <property name="name"  value="Zara" />
      <property name="age"  value="11"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for student2 bean -->
   <bean id="student2" class="com.Student">
      <property name="name"  value="Nuha" />
      <property name="age"  value="2"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you have 3 general approaches...

1. Create a child context and in the child context override beans in the parent context (they will replace them)
2. Use a profile
3. Use a customisation of the annotation when injecting the bean

The first option means that customers when they wish to replace the "core" beans with their own ones simply need to create a new factory which is a child of the core factory. As long as the bean in the child has the same name as the on in core all is well.

The second one means the default bean will be in the "default" (no profile) and then the replacement will be in a specific profile. These replacement beans will then override the beans in no profile when that profile is active. Replacement only happens against bean name not against type so when using this approach you have to ensure the new bean has the same name as the original and the injection annotation specifies the name of the bean ala

```
@Inject
@Named("dataSource")
private DataSource storageRepository;
```

The third option requires the following to appear in the annotation when using a bean

```
@Resource(name = "${dataSource}")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Then when using this you will need a parameter called dataSource and needs to be set to the specific bean name you want to inject into that location. 
e.g.

> dataSource=enterpriseDataSource

then the bean named enterpriseDataSource will be injected into that location.

The way I see it approach 1 is arguably the closest fit to what you're looking for. It sounds like you have a "core" factory that you supply that customers depend on so they don't really have ownership of your source code. AFAIK approach 1 is also the only one that will allow autowire by type to work.

Approach 2 is a better fit for when you want to run in different modes... i.e. in dev, test or production mode. The reason for this is you can only override beans that are not in a profile. You can't override a bean already in a profile with a bean in another profile with this approach.

Approach 3 is in fact what I tend to use the most because it does not require profiles or factory hierarchy and allows swapping in of a different bean simply by changing a parameter's value. I wish however I did not have to keep specifying the bean name however. Something else that is possible - and something I use a lot - is swapping in a whole new config file via activation of a different profile.